# Jquery - Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some tabs inside an accordion that don't seem to be working and the error in the console is:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

I've googled the error and still can't seem to get a handle on what might be causing it. From looking at the code it all looks ok as mostly it's just straightforward.

The HTML is:

```
<div class="access-privilages">
                <!-- Accordions -->
                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_hradmin">First</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_hradmin" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                                <!-- Tabs -->
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="active">
                                        <a id="personal" href="#">Personal Information</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a id="financial" href="#">Financial Information</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                <div class="tabContent" id="tabContent_personal">


                                </div>
                                <div class="tabContent" id="tabContent_financial">

                                </div>  

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse_rmgadmin" class="collapsed">Second</a>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapse_rmgadmin" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <p>Second Section</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

And the JS is pretty simple:

```
$(".nav a").click(function(e) {
                $(this).tab("show");

                var tabContent = "#tabContent_" + this.id;

                $("#tabContent_personal").hide();
                $("#tabContent_financial").hide();
                $(tabContent).show();
            });
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxy8g7L8/). Any ideas?

Comment: .tab() <--- What library is this function a part of? That is not a standard jQuery function -- so I suspect that your issue lies in whatever library is associated with tab() - and it is having trouble with your hashes being used as your hrefs.

Try using "javascript:void(0)" instead of # in your anchors.

Comment: You are missing the jquery lib there... nothing more

Comment: I assumed bootstrap?

Comment: I have the JQuery library attached

Comment: Not in the fiddle... and when I added it everything worked. You need to provide an example where we can actually see the error.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxy8g7L8/1/ working example - attach Jquery library

Comment: If you'll look at the documentation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs) it requires the markup to have target within the `href` attribute:

`<a href="#home" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="true">Home</a>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxy8g7L8/3/ - Non-working - with Jquery attached

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf its not working with jQuery 3.2.1, use jQuery 2.2.4. Works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap uses the content of the `href` to query for the container that should be shown.

But your links only have `#` as `href`:

```
<a id="personal" href="#">
```

So the query will be `$('#')`, and that is is the reason for the error message:

If you write:

```
<a id="personal" href="#tabContent_personal">
```

and

```
<a id="financial" href="#tabContent_financial">
```

it will work fine.